# multiple image upload doesn't insert data

Tags: php

I'm trying to overwrite my code to accept multiple images, but somehow it doesn't work. It used to do before, with only one image, but I'd need <=5 images to upload at the same time. 
This is my input:

```
 <input type='file' name='file' multiple accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg" />
```

and this is the uploader:

```
    if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
            $selectid = $conn->prepare("SELECT max(id) AS id FROM cards");
            $selectid->execute();

            $cardid = $selectid->get_result()->fetch_array()['id'];

            for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); $count++){
            $imgData = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$count]);
        }
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cardimages(image, cardid) VALUES(?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("si", $imgData, $cardid);
            $stmt->execute();                              

    }
    }
```

It doesn't upload anything. Don't really understand why.

Comment: can you share your form in your post?

Comment: ```<form action="imgupload.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in your form

```
<form action="imgupload.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <input type='file' name='file[]' multiple accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg" />
     <!-- make it file[] instead of file -->
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

in your `imgupload.php` loop though `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

```
if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
        foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $i => $tmp_name) {
            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i])) {

                $selectid = $conn->prepare("SELECT max(id) AS id FROM cards");
                $selectid->execute();

                $cardid = $selectid->get_result()->fetch_array()['id'];

                for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][[$i]]); $count++){
                $imgData = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);
            }
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cardimages(image, cardid) VALUES(?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("si", $imgData, $cardid);
                $stmt->execute();                              

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is still wrong. My database doesn't gt the data with this. Even if I upload 1 image or more.

Comment: There isn't any errors, it just redirects me to the page I set but the data doesn't show up in database.

Comment: Got it. The problem was this: ```for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][[$i]]); $count++)``` There was ```[[]]``` instead of ```[]``` Thnaks for your help.

Comment: Also accepted it, but please edit that line so others can use it too.

Answer (score 0):

This because you are try to bind three values where you have place for two placeholder.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cardimages(image, cardid) VALUES(?, ?)"); // Two placeholder
$stmt->bind_param("si", $imgData, $cardid); // Three values
```

Check your table schema and adjust it. NUmber of placeholders must be same number as values.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: "si" isn't a value. That means my first valueis a string, the second one is an integer.

Comment: The format is ```$stmt->bindParam(<question mark placeholders number>, <variable>, <data type>);```.  Each variable should be given its own line. This this
```
$stmt->bind_param(1, $imgData, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bind_param(2, $cardid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: My format used to work this way without the multiple image part.